# How to operate on objects within MS Access VBA

Tags: excel, object, iteration, vba

I have got a problem. First iteration goes correctly, but second one breaks at `Set tdf = db.TableDefs("temp_table")` (Access can't find "temp_table" although it is created a line above). It is definitely something wrong with the pointer of new imported table.

```
    dirfilename = Dir(strfilename & "\")
    Do While dirfilename <> ""

    DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel8, "temp_table", 
    strfilename & "\" & dirfilename, True
    Set tdf = db.TableDefs("temp_table")
    .
    .
    .
    .
    db.TableDefs.Refresh
    dirfilename = Dir
    Loop
```

Can any of you help me?

Comment: The subsequent iterations are trying to append records to table created in the first iteration, not create a new table. Are you trying to import multiple spreadsheets? Why do you need TableDefs?

Comment: I am trying to append data from consecutive workbooks that are in the same folder (hence I placed 'dir' function). After first iteration, second "temp_table" (I forgot to paste in the post an excerpt of deleting previous "temp_table") still contains contemporary values, but it is a new table. I delete previous one. Of course, I can call them "temp_table2" etc. but I'm afraid the problem will still occur, and it is not correct as for programming standards.

Comment: Personally, if sheet structure never changes, I would not create and delete table. I would just insert and delete records of permanent table - even though it is called a 'temp' table, table is permanent and records are temporary. Why a temp table anyway? What happens to these records?

Comment: The problem is, the sheet structure changes (temp table's structures changes) and I set up temp tables in order to do some modification inside them to prepare one standard.You're right to just insert values if the structure didn't change. But it unfortunately does.

Answer (score 0):

I am not able to replicate the issue today, although have in the past.

Try:

`Application.RefreshDatabaseWindow`

or

`DoCmd.SelectObject acTable, "temp_table", True`

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured it out. I needed to insert 'db.TableDefs.Refresh' between command of importing data and setting a pointer (tdf). I also had to call temporary tables uniquely, so 'temp_table1','temp_table2' etc. It works correctly now.